# Contract method always return 0

Tags: solidity, web3js

I started to learn solidity and want to code something, but I'm struggling with simple call function to contract.
Can you point me out what I'm doing wrong?

Here is simple gits: https://gist.github.com/xaxes/0da37b5c2585445d571526db42110eb3

My problem is when I'm trying to set int value in the contract and then get it, 0 is always returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use `call` to invoke the `set` function in index.js on line 24. `call` doesn't send a transaction, but instead runs a simulation of the function. As `set` alters the state of the contract, however, `sendTransaction` should be used instead.

Also, you should `call` `get` inside the callback of line 24 in index.js, so that the program waits until the `set` transaction was mined before calling `get`

Change

```
instance.set.call(10, (err, ok) => console.log('set', err, ok))
instance.get.call((err, ok) => console.log('get', err, ok.toString())) /* (1) Here why 10 is not returned */
```

to

```
instance.set.call(10, (err, ok) => {
    console.log('set', err, ok);
    instance.get.call((err, ok) => console.log('get', err, ok.toString())) /* (1) Here why 10 is not returned */
});
```

and it should work

Comment: You'll also need to wait for the transaction to be mined. If you call `get` immediately, you'll still get the old value. (Possibly not if you're using a local test network that mines blocks immediately, but for the real network, you'll need to call `get` after the transaction for `set` has been mined.)